# constructor on type "" not found when inheriting forms c# forms

Tags: c#

created a form that inherits from another form, but for some reason I am getting the error constructor on type "baseForm" not found. This is the inheriting class constructor:

```
public partial class loadHtmlFormsDatabaseForm :      NEA_Official.createHtmlFormsForm
{
    List<field> listOfFields = new List<field>();
    static string username1;
    int originalListOfFieldsCount;
    htmlFormsProject loadedProject;

    public loadHtmlFormsDatabaseForm(htmlFormsProject loadProject, string username) : base(username1)
    {
        username1 = username;
        loadedProject = loadProject;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

This is the constructor for the base class:

```
    public partial class createHtmlFormsForm : Form
{
    List<field> listOfFields = new List<field>();
    string username = "";

    public createHtmlFormsForm(string username1)
    {
        username = username1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: The looks fine. I could repro the same case and it worked without any error. Can you tell if it's runtime error or compile time error? Which line of code shows the error?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the program runs fine, but it isn't allowing me to look at the design of the form

Comment: What happens when you try to see the design of the form?

Answer (score 7):

You can fix it by overload the constructor with  no parameter in base class like this:

```
public partial class createHtmlFormsForm : Form
{
 List<field> listOfFields = new List<field>();
 string username = "";

 public createHtmlFormsForm(string username1)
 {
    username = username1;
    InitializeComponent();
 }
 public createHtmlFormsForm()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
 }
}
```

If you don't need constructor with no parameter you can create it private :

```
public partial class createHtmlFormsForm : Form
{
 List<field> listOfFields = new List<field>();
 string username = "";

 public createHtmlFormsForm(string username1)
 {
    username = username1;
    InitializeComponent();
 }
// private contructor with no parameter
 private createHtmlFormsForm()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
 }
}
```

or you can use Obsolete Attribute:

```
public partial class createHtmlFormsForm : Form
{
 List<field> listOfFields = new List<field>();
 string username = "";

 public createHtmlFormsForm(string username1)
 {
    username = username1;
    InitializeComponent();
 }

 [Obsolete("Designer only", true)]
 public createHtmlFormsForm()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it foud but send wrong parameter.

`: base(username1)` change to `: base(username)`